# how to import {Quill} in next js? or how can I add hr tag in Quill editor with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, quill

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELFoV.png)

my error code

---

hello, I want to custom Quill editor like Divider.
but, when I use the {Quill}, I have error like that.
how can I solve that?

---

here is my code

```
import { Quill } from 'react-quill';

const quill = Quill;

    const modules = useMemo(
        () => ({
            toolbar: {
                container:  /**/               
                handlers: {
                    hr: () => {
                        setHtmlContent((prev: string) => {
                            return prev + '<hr/>';
                        });
                    },
                },
            },
        }),

        []
    );

    const formats = [
        /**/
        'hr',
    ];

    return (           
            <ReactQuill
                theme="snow"
                modules={modules}
                formats={formats}
                value={htmlContent}
                onChange={(content, delta, source, editor) => {
                    setHtmlContent(editor.getHTML());
                }}
            />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `react-quill` package uses some browser APIs like `document` which are not available on the server. The error is caused when Next.js is Server-Side-Rendering the page. You can fix this by loading the package on the client only with a `dynamic` import.

Here, try to import like this instead:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Quill = dynamic(() => import('react-quill'), {
  // Set this to `false` so it is only loaded on the client.
  ssr: false,
  // You can also add an indicator while the component is loading.
  loading: () => <p>Loading ...</p>, 
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add 'use client' at the first line and use dynamic for you to instantiate your Quill editor

`const ReactQuill = useMemo(() => dynamic(() => import('react-quill'), { ssr: false }), []);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).